# Are the Server Fault and Super User domains officially supported by the API?

Tags: discussion

Are the Server Fault and Super User domains officially supported by the API?

I don't find this information in the FAQ, although I can browse http://api.superuser.com/0.8/stats for example.

**EDIT:**
Information added to the FAQ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, Serverfault, Superuser are supported just like StackOverflow.

There was a post from *Geoff Dalgas* in dev.meta, but I don't see the post here related to that

Let me quote some part of the post

> **Super User and Server Fault are ready
>   for API testing**
>
> All methods are currently identical to
>   the current list for Stack Overflow -
>   just replace the host name:

```
http://api.superuser.com/{version}/{method} for Super User

http://api.serverfault.com/{version}/{method} for Server Fault
```

Comment: @S.Mark Perfect, i think it should be added to the faq.[OT: can you still access dev.meta?]

Comment: @system dev.meta is no longer available.